# If $2^{2x}+2^{2-x}=15$ then $2^x+2^{-x}=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $2^{2x}+2^{2-x}=15$ then $2^x+2^{-x}=?$

I thought of taking square of $2^x+2^{-x}$ which is $2^{2x}+2^{-2x}+2$, but I couldn't go further than that. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe introduce variable named for the new quantities, then it will become clearer.

Comment: Try to solve by assuming $y=2^x$.

Comment: You took the square of the target quantity. In this case, it's better to manipulate the source quantity first, like Soham Saha suggested. By the way, I have solved it without brute-force calculations and it's pretty cool that you don't need to find $x$. Please try it again.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $2^x=y$

First Solution:
$$2^{2x}+2^{2-x}=y^2 + \frac{4}{y}=15$$
$$y^2 + 1 =16 - \frac{4}{y}$$
$$y + \frac{1}{y} =\frac{16}{y} - \frac{4}{y^2}=4\times (15 - y^2) - \frac{4}{y^2}=60 - 4(y^2+\frac{1}{y^2})=60-4[(y+\frac{1}{y})^2-2]=68-4(y+\frac{1}{y})^2$$

$$4(y+\frac{1}{y})^2 + (y + \frac{1}{y}) -68=[4(y + \frac{1}{y})+17]\times [(y + \frac{1}{y})_-4]=0 $$

$y + \frac{1}{y}=2^x+2^{-x}=\frac{-17}{4}$ NA

$y + \frac{1}{y}=2^x+2^{-x}=4$

Second Solution:
$$y^2 + \frac{4}{y}=15, y\neq 0$$
$$y^3-15y+4=(y+4)(y^2-4y+1)=0$$
$$y=-4, y=2\mp\sqrt3$$

$2^x=-4$ NA

$2^x=2 \mp\sqrt3$

$2^x +2^{-x} = 2\mp\sqrt3 + \frac{1}{2\mp\sqrt3} = 4 $

Comment: Yo do not need find the roots. Note that, $$\small {y^2-4y+1=0\implies y+\frac 1y=4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$2^x = a$

$a^2 + \frac{4}{a} = 15$

$a^3 - 15a = -4$

$a(a^2 - 15) = -4$

$a = -4$

$2^x + 2 ^{-x} = -4 + -\frac{1}{4} = -\frac{17}{4}$

---

$a^3-15a+4=(a+4)(a^2-4a+1)=0$
$a^2 -4a + 1 = 0 \implies a + \frac{1}{a} = 4 = 2^x + 2^{-x}$

Comment: Note that $2^x > 0$ for every real number $x$.

Comment: Thanks @N.F.Taussig